# Remove duplicates records from sum statement using SQL server

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, count, case

Hi i have a table in which it has some duplicate records i want to remove all duplicate records and get the total count for that condition . I have tried following query here in first query it will include duplicate records also .

```
1> select count(fd.FarmerRegNo) as TotalRecord,
 sum(case when fd.TSStatus='Approved' and Status!=0  then 1 else 0 end) Approved,
 sum(case when fd.TSStatus='Pending' and fd.Status=0 then 1 else 0 end) Pending,
 from FarmerDetail as fd 

2> select count(distinct FarmerRegNo) as [Approved]  from FarmerDetail where TSStatus='Approved'
```

[image]

see the image i want to get the 2nd table value in first table approved column how to remove duplicates for this condition

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select 
    count(distinct fd.FarmerRegNo) as TotalRecord,
    count(distinct case when fd.TSStatus = 'Approved' and Status != 0   then fd.FarmerRegNo end) Approved,
    count(distinct case when fd.TSStatus = 'Pending'  and Status = 0 then fd.FarmerRegNoend) Pending,
from FarmerDetail as fd
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional `count(distinct)`:

```
select count(fd.FarmerRegNo) as TotalRecord,
       count(distinct case when fd.TSStatus = 'Approved' and fd.Status <> 0 then fd.FarmerRegNo end) as Approved,
       count(distinct case when fd.TSStatus = 'Pending' and fd.Status = 0 then fd.FarmerRegNo end) as Pending,
from FarmerDetail fd ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query with sub query

```
    select count(fd.FarmerRegNo) as TotalRecord,
    (select count(distinct FarmerRegNo) from FarmerDetail where TSStatus='Approved') as Approved,
    sum(case when fd.TSStatus='Pending' and fd.Status=0 then 1 else 0 end) Pending,
    from FarmerDetail as fd
```